# Why can I declare a function without the "throws" keyword?

Tags: java, oop, exception, inheritance, interface

Consider the following code:

```
public interface I1 {
 public void bar1() throws IOException; 
} 

public interface I2 extends I1 { 
 public void bar2() throws Exception; 
} 

public interface I3 { 
 public void bar3() throws Exception; 
} 

public abstract class A implements I2 { 
 public void bar2() throws Exception{}; 
 public void bar3() throws Exception{}; 
 protected abstract void bar4(); 
 protected void bar5() {}; 
}
```

Now, I created a class, `B` as follows:

```
public class B extends A implements I3 {

    @Override
    protected void bar4() {}

    public void bar1()  {}

}
```

Why is the compiler letting me do that? I mean, shouldn't it be:
`public void bar1() throws IOException;`

Comment: You can think of it this way: _I1_ tells us about what is the worst can that can happen, because everybody accepting a class implementing _I1_ needs to be prepared for that worst case. Now you implement `bar1()`, but it doesn't actually throw `IOException`. What is the worst that can happen? The implementation is clearly _less worse_ than throwing an `IOException`. If some other class uses a class implementing _I1_, it won't change anything. The implementation is prepared to handle `IOExceptions`, but they just never happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When overriding you cannot throw Broader or newer exception. Not throwing a super class method's exception is allowed.

The overriding method must NOT throw checked exceptions that are new or broader than those declared by the                 overridden method. For example, a method that declares a FileNotFoundException cannot be overridden by a method that declares a SQLException, Exception, or any other non-runtime exception unless it's a subclass of FileNotFoundException.

Comment: Why `public void bar1() throws NullPointerException {}` did work? it's not a subclass of `IOException`.

Comment: NullPointerException is not checked exception. So, even this is OK. When overriding, only CHECKED exceptions are restricted to narrower or lesser exceptions. IOException is checked Exception and hence the rule applied.

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance lets you make functions more specific.

You can reduce the number of things you throw, you can return a subtype of the return type, you can accept a supertype of a parameter type.

This is because any possible call to your method most be a legal call to the super method, but the reverse does not need to be true.

In other words in your example:

```
new B().bar1()
```

You know it doesn't throw the exception, you don't need to catch.

```
((A)new B()).bar1()
```

You need to catch the exception as since you are now processing any A or subclass of A you might need to handle it.

If you tried to do the reverse though and create a class C:

```
public class C extends A implements I3 {

    @Override
    protected void bar4() {}

    public void bar1() throws IOException, SomeOtherException {}

}
```

This would not be allowed as now if you tried to use a C as an A you are not going to be catching SomeOtherException.